# Phing Deployment - Git repo - Script

Tags: git, deployment, remote-server, phing

I want to be able to deploy files from my local system (git repo) to different servers.

I have 3 branches. `Mater`,`staging` and `develop`. Each branch should deploy to corresponding server.

My constants:

- `git` is not installed on any of the servers. So `checking out with post commit hook` solution won't work
- Do not want to checkout entire files and folders every time. Only updated files from the local branches should be deployed.
- Ideally want to pull the updated files directly from branch and deploy them instead of copying and pushing files from local file system to the servers.
- It should be `SSH` deploy. No passwords. It uses `SSH Keys`
- I installed `Phing` just for this purpose. But I am not sure where to go from here keeping the above constraints in mind.
- I am open to any other suggestion, other than `Phing` as a solution
- Note that the deployment is from `local` (Windows) machine to `remote web server`.

Any script / article that you can provide / point to?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not make packages/jars/RPMs/etc? What's the target servers' platform?

Comment: Its LAMP stack. Just PHP files.

Comment: I'd recommend either phar'ing (http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) or packages (like  DEBs/RPMs/etc, depending on your platform. e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-debpkg/index.html). Ideally you'd wrap this into a continuous integration process.

Comment: Packaging and then unpacking, rpms, etc are not a best way I guess. You would need additional permissions to do so. The goal is for me to pull a `git` repo and push it to `server`.

Comment: oh, ok. Have you looked at Capistrano? http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html

Comment: Yes, I did. It needs ruby on the remote server as well. Wont work. :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25177/discussion-between-jchapa-and-kevin-rave)

Comment: Otherwise, I'd say you might be leaving yourself with a simple tar->scp->untar

Comment: `git` is lightweight, you could install the bare minimum to use the repositories at the servers, and use the checked out files directly. Haven't pushed to a full (not bare) repository, check out what happens (i.e., if changed files get checked out or something else has to be set up for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [scp task](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#ScpTask) to copy files to the remote server, and the [ssh task](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#SshTask) to execute anything on the remote server that is needed such as clearing caches / restarting apache / moving webroot symlinks. The only disadvantage from your above requirements is it will push all files, not just files that have changed. To do this however, you could look into the [FileSync](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#FileSyncTask) Task